# PHP copy a file and change the permissions of the copy

Tags: php, copy

I am using php copy() function and it works fine, the only thing is when I copy the file the permissions are set to: -rw-r--r-- and I would like to make them readable and writable (777)

is this possible?

```
copy("../virtual-tours/PTGuiViewer.js", "../virtual-tours/" . $brandNewFolderName . "/PTGuiViewer.js");
```

Comment: You could call [chmod()](http://www.php.net/chmod) after copying the file.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
chmod("full-path-of-file",0777);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `chmod` as below:

```
copy("../virtual-tours/PTGuiViewer.js", "../virtual-tours/" . $brandNewFolderName . "/PTGuiViewer.js");
chmod("../virtual-tours/" . $brandNewFolderName . "/PTGuiViewer.js", 0777);
```

Notice: Leading zero in `0777` is important.